# Remove title based on viewport width

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Is it possible to remove the Y-axis title based on the viewport width?

I can achieve this with CSS like so:

```
@media (max-width:480px) {
  .highcharts-yaxis-title {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

The problem with that, however, is that there is still a big gap where the title should appear.

Comment: If you're OK to use Javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/39xBU/55/

Comment: What is the css declaration for the .highcharts-yaxis-title element?

Comment: Your declaration should work and there should not ba any gap when the title disapears. There must be something else creating that gap. Could you provide a working demo reproducing your issue?

Comment: Answer by @JugalThakkar is good one - and just a word of explanation. media-queries won't work because everything in SVG is computed and displayed using x/y position. The same for width/height. When you hide just SVG element, that won't reflow anything on a chart, you need to manually manage this space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function that checks on `chartWidth`, and accordingly either enables the title or disables it using the [Axis.Update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update) method

```
var isTitleShowing=true;
function updateAxisTitle(chart) {
    if (chart.chartWidth < 500 && isTitleShowing) {
        console.log('Disabling');
        isTitleShowing = false;
        $.each(chart.yAxis, function (index, yAxis) {
            yAxis.update({
                title: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }, false);
        });
        // Calling redraw inside the redraw handler itself throws an exception
        // Delaying the redraw by a few ms lets the current redraw cycle finish
        setTimeout(function () {
            chart.redraw();
        }, 20);
    } else if (chart.chartWidth >= 500 && !isTitleShowing) {
        console.log('Enabling');
        isTitleShowing = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < chart.yAxis.length; i++) {
            chart.yAxis[i].update({
                title: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }, false);
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            chart.redraw();
        }, 20);
    }
}
```

You can add this function as a handler to the [`redraw`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.redraw) and [`load`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load) events

```
chart: {
    events: {
        redraw: function () {
            updateAxisTitle(this);
        },
        load: function () {
            updateAxisTitle(this);
        }
    }
}
```

[Handling Chart Resizing @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/4p8fnwyo/)

Comment: i ended up doing something similar to this. unfortunate that it cant be done in css, but this is the next best thing.

Answer (score 0):

It should be working... unless you are adding something inside that is affecting the height, have you tried with something like this?

```
@media (max-width:480px) {
  .highcharts-yaxis-title {
    display:none;
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: that leaves a gap. it seems like highcharts doesnt resize the rest of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check if [this](http://jsfiddle.net/39xBU/172/) could help you.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width()
    if(windowWidth<=480){
        $('#y1').click();
    }
})
```